# PipedOutputStream in HashMap for threads

Tags: java, multithreading, iostream

I have couple of threads that run in background. They do share a common `HashMap`.
Is it possible to store (safely) `PipedOutputStream` there?

I have this following scenario:

When first background thread receives a specific event, it should start read  text data from a huge file into a buffer.

Second background thread (they are independent) should be notified somehow and then read data from the buffer (pipe) as it arrives.

Because all threads can access the `HashMap`, is it ok to store there all the streams?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ConcurrentHashMap.  I don't see much point in using a Pipe here as files will be read by the OS in advance of where you are reading anyway.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment, I want to read data line by line from a file, and write into the pipe from first thread, and read the arriving data for process, from the pipe in second thread.

Comment: I understand that's what you want to do, but if its for performance reasons you are likely to be disappointed as the OS reads the data before you as for it and add it to the file descriptors buffer (which is what a pipe uses also) which is what you read. i.e. you are likely to be duplicating what the OS does for you already.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. But I will gain performance on a different stage, I haven't explained the full flow (cause it was not important for the question). The "old" method was reading data from start to end   and writing it to another file and only then the new file was processed. With the new method i  skip the temp file.

Comment: Does the old process have to write to an OutputStream?

Comment: How I would make it more performant is to simplify the interaction between the threads.  This largely depend on what they do and how much you can change.

Comment: the problem that i can't change much. The only change i can do is to use the common hashmap, read text line by line and pass them to other thread.

Comment: p.s. I don't have to use piped stream if it's a problem i can implement buffer differently... but it must act like piped buffer, while first thread reading data second thread processing it.

Comment: That's entirely possible.  I would try to use ExecutorService to call the first and second tasks in a pool of threads if you can. This way you can be sure they are likely to be running at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control the thread execution, there are couple of lets call them "exit points" that I can use and  add my code there.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not synchronized, so you have to add your logic or use a synchronized collection. As for the streams, ince you can only write to an OutputStream and only read from an InputStream, you will have no problem writing from one thread and reading from another.